# Is there a way to combine these similar jQuery event listener functions?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple jquery event listener functions that either show or hide a checkmark button based on if there is any input in the input box. The functions are practically identical minus the ID names. I'm wondering if there's a way to combine these similar functions into one, maybe using a for loop or forEach method? Any advice on how to achieve this is greatly appreciated!
Code is listed down below but I also made a codepen sample.

```js
$("#chwValue").on("input", function() {
  $("#addChw").removeAttr("style");
  if ($(this).val() === "") {
    $("#addChw").hide();
  }
});

$("#eleValue").on("input", function() {
  $("#addEle").removeAttr("style");
  if ($(this).val() === "") {
    $("#addEle").hide();
  }
});

$("#stmValue").on("input", function() {
  $("#addStm").removeAttr("style");
  if ($(this).val() === "") {
    $("#addStm").hide();
  }
});

$("#hhwValue").on("input", function() {
  $("#addHhw").removeAttr("style");
  if ($(this).val() === "") {
    $("#addHhw").hide();
  }
});

$("#gasValue").on("input", function() {
  $("#addGas").removeAttr("style");
  if ($(this).val() === "") {
    $("#addGas").hide();
  }
});

$("#wtrValue").on("input", function() {
  $("#addWtr").removeAttr("style");
  if ($(this).val() === "") {
    $("#addWtr").hide();
  }
});

$("#peakChwValue").on("input", function() {
  $("#addPeakChw").removeAttr("style");
  if ($(this).val() === "") {
    $("#addPeakChw").hide();
  }
});

$("#laborValue").on("input", function() {
  $("#addLabor").removeAttr("style");
  if ($(this).val() === "") {
    $("#addLabor").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.checkMark:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  transform: scale(1.1)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />

<table id="tableData" class="table text-light text-end table-borderless inputTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class='text-center bordered'>
      <th></th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">CHW
        <span class='units'>[tonhr]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">ELE
        <span class='units'>[kWh]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">STM
        <span class='units'>[lb]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">HHW
        <span class='units'>[mmbtu]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">GAS
        <span class='units'>[CCF]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">WTR
        <span class='units'>[kgal]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">Peak CHW
        <span class='units'>[ton]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">Labor
        <span class='units'>[Hours]</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 100px" class="bordered">Baseline</th>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="chwValue" class="chwInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="eleValue" class="eleInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="stmValue" class="stmInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="hhwValue" class="hhwInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="gasValue" class="gasInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="wtrValue" class="wtrInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="peakChwValue" class="peakChwInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="laborValue" class="laborInput">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='text-center borderTop'>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <i id="addChw" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addEle" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addStm" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addHhw" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addGas" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addWtr" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addPeakChw" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addLabor" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Suggestion: to your `input` elements, add an attribute, like `data-checkmark="addChw"` only put in the corresponding ID for the `i` you want to toggle. Then have a single event handler, like `$('input:text').on('input', function () { $('#' + this.getAttribute('data-checkmark')).toggle(this.value !== '');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
var mappings = { //Need a better name
  '#chwValue': '#addChw',
  '#hhwValue': '#addHhw'
  // Add the rest of the mappings here
}

Object.keys(mappings).forEach(function(key) {
  var value = mappings[key];
  $(key).on("input", function() {
    $(value).removeAttr("style");
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
      $(value).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give all the inputs a common class. Give them an attribute that refers to the related `addXxx` element.

```js
$(".inputValue").on("input", function() {
  let rel = $($(this).data("add"));
  rel.removeAttr("style");
  if ($(this).val() === "") {
    rel.hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.checkMark:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  transform: scale(1.1)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableData" class="table text-light text-end table-borderless inputTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class='text-center bordered'>
      <th></th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">CHW
        <span class='units'>[tonhr]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">ELE
        <span class='units'>[kWh]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">STM
        <span class='units'>[lb]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">HHW
        <span class='units'>[mmbtu]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">GAS
        <span class='units'>[CCF]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">WTR
        <span class='units'>[kgal]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">Peak CHW
        <span class='units'>[ton]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">Labor
        <span class='units'>[Hours]</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 100px" class="bordered">Baseline</th>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="chwValue" class="chwInput inputValue" data-add="#addChw">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="eleValue" class="eleInput inputValue" data-add="#addEle">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="stmValue" class="stmInput inputValue" data-add="#addStm">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="hhwValue" class="hhwInput inputValue" data-add="#addHhw">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="gasValue" class="gasInput inputValue" data-add="#addGas">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="wtrValue" class="wtrInput inputValue" data-add="#addWtr">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="peakChwValue" class="peakChwInput inputValue" data-add="#addPeakChw">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="laborValue" class="laborInput inputValue" data-add="#addLabor">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='text-center borderTop'>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <i id="addChw" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark">x</i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addEle" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark">x</i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addStm" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark">x</i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addHhw" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark">x</i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addGas" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark">x</i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addWtr" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark">x</i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addPeakChw" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark">x</i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addLabor" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark">x</i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in a more DRY manner you can relate the cells in the columns by their index. When an `input` element raises an `input` event you can capture its index within the parent `tr`, then retrieve the corresponding icon cell from the following row by that same index. Something like this:

```js
let $iconCells = $('.icon-row td');

$('.input-row input').on('input', e => {
  let $input = $(e.target)
  let index = $input.closest('td').index();
  $iconCells.eq(index).find('i').toggle($input.val().length > 0);
});
```

```css
.checkMark:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  transform: scale(1.1)
}

.icon-row i {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />
<table id="tableData" class="table text-light text-end table-borderless inputTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class='text-center bordered'>
      <th></th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">
        CHW
        <span class='units'>[tonhr]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">
        ELE
        <span class='units'>[kWh]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col"> 
        STM
        <span class='units'>[lb]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">
        HHW
        <span class='units'>[mmbtu]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">
        GAS
        <span class='units'>[CCF]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">
        WTR
        <span class='units'>[kgal]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">
        Peak CHW
        <span class='units'>[ton]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">
        Labor
        <span class='units'>[Hours]</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="input-row">
      <th style="width: 100px" class="bordered">Baseline</th>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" name="chwValue" class="chwInput" /> 
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" name="eleValue" class="eleInput" />
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" name="stmValue" class="stmInput" />
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" name="hhwValue" class="hhwInput" />
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" name="gasValue" class="gasInput" />
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" name="wtrValue" class="wtrInput" />
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" name="peakChwValue" class="peakChwInput" /> 
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" name="laborValue" class="laborInput" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center borderTop icon-row">
      <td></td>
      <td><i class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i></td>
      <td><i class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i></td>
      <td><i class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i></td>
      <td><i class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i></td>
      <td><i class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i></td>
      <td><i class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i></td>
      <td><i class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i></td>
      <td><i class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the relationships in an array of objects and iterate through.

```js
let objs = [
{'chwValue': 'addChw'},
{'eleValue': 'addEle'},
{'stmValue': 'addStm'},
{'hhwValue': 'addHhw'},
{'gasValue': 'addGas'},
{'wtrValue': 'addWtr'},
{'peakChwValue': 'addPeakChw'},
{'laborValue': 'addLabor'}];

objs.forEach(e => {
  let [input, el] = Object.entries(e)[0];
  $(`#${input}`).on("input", function() {
    $(`#${el}`).removeAttr("style");
    if ($(this).val() === "") $(`$${el}`).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.checkMark:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  transform: scale(1.1)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<table id="tableData" class="table text-light text-end table-borderless inputTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class='text-center bordered'>
      <th></th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">CHW
        <span class='units'>[tonhr]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">ELE
        <span class='units'>[kWh]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">STM
        <span class='units'>[lb]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">HHW
        <span class='units'>[mmbtu]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">GAS
        <span class='units'>[CCF]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">WTR
        <span class='units'>[kgal]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">Peak CHW
        <span class='units'>[ton]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">Labor
        <span class='units'>[Hours]</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 100px" class="bordered">Baseline</th>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="chwValue" class="chwInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="eleValue" class="eleInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="stmValue" class="stmInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="hhwValue" class="hhwInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="gasValue" class="gasInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="wtrValue" class="wtrInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="peakChwValue" class="peakChwInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="laborValue" class="laborInput">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='text-center borderTop'>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <i id="addChw" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addEle" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addStm" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addHhw" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addGas" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addWtr" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addPeakChw" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addLabor" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$("#chwValue, #eleValue, #stmValue, #hhwValue, #gasValue, #wtrValue, #peakChwValue, #laborValue").on("input", function() {

  //get the id selector from the id value (everything before 'Value')
  let idName = $(this).attr('id').split('Value')[0]

  //capitalize the first character
  idName = idName[0].toUpperCase() + idName.slice(1);

  //add the id selector dynamically
  $("#add"+idName).removeAttr("style");
  if ($(this).val() === "") {
    $("#add"+idName).hide();
  }
});
```

```js
$("#chwValue, #eleValue, #stmValue, #hhwValue, #gasValue, #wtrValue, #peakChwValue, #laborValue").on("input", function() {

      //get the id selector from the id value (everything before 'Value')
      let idName = $(this).attr('id').split('Value')[0]

      //capitalize the first character
      idName = idName[0].toUpperCase() + idName.slice(1);

      //add the id selector dynamically
      $("#add"+idName).removeAttr("style");
      if ($(this).val() === "") {
        $("#add"+idName).hide();
      }
    });
```

```css
.checkMark:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  transform: scale(1.1)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />

<table id="tableData" class="table text-light text-end table-borderless inputTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class='text-center bordered'>
      <th></th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">CHW
        <span class='units'>[tonhr]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">ELE
        <span class='units'>[kWh]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">STM
        <span class='units'>[lb]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">HHW
        <span class='units'>[mmbtu]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">GAS
        <span class='units'>[CCF]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">WTR
        <span class='units'>[kgal]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">Peak CHW
        <span class='units'>[ton]</span>
      </th>
      <th class="bordered" scope="col">Labor
        <span class='units'>[Hours]</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 100px" class="bordered">Baseline</th>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="chwValue" class="chwInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="eleValue" class="eleInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="stmValue" class="stmInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="hhwValue" class="hhwInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="gasValue" class="gasInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="wtrValue" class="wtrInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="peakChwValue" class="peakChwInput">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center inputBorder">
        <input type="text" id="laborValue" class="laborInput">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='text-center borderTop'>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <i id="addChw" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addEle" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addStm" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addHhw" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addGas" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addWtr" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addPeakChw" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i id="addLabor" style="display: none" class="far fa-check-circle fa-3x checkMark"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```